# Elegantify / simply this js?

Tags: jquery, simplify

I'm doing a bunch of enabling / disabling of selects with checkboxes and inputs and I'm wondering if I can simply this js using loops, variables or compound statements? It just feels like a lot of code for relatively simple functionality.

Here's a fiddle of what I'm doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/555f2yan/1/

```
//check to see if checkboxes are checked and enable / disable accordingly
$(".zone-on-off").each(function() {
if (this.checked) {
$(this).parent("div").siblings("div").children("select").prop("disabled", false);
} else {
$(this).parent("div").siblings("div").children("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
}
});
// enable / disable selects per on/off checkbox
$(".zone-on-off").click(function() {
if (this.checked) {
$(this).parent("div").siblings("div").children("select").prop("disabled", false);
} else {
$(this).parent("div").siblings("div").children("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
}
});
// enable selects when name is inputted
$(".zone-name").change(function() {
if (this.val().length) {
$(this).parent("div").siblings("div").children("select").prop("disabled", false);
} else {
$(this).parent("div").siblings("div").children("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
}
});
// input name on enter
$('.zone-name').keypress(function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
$(this).blur();
$(this).parent("div").siblings("div").children("select").prop("disabled", false);
}
});
```

Comment: Hmm... the enable selects when name is inputted part doesn't seem to be working?- I think you want $(this).val.

Comment: Would you mind using some indentation?

Comment: This might be a good question for the Code Review site (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is a good place to ask about code that technically works, but could probably be improved in some way. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

This might achieve your requirements. In other words, it should still work just like before. I've just reduced the code.

```
$(function () {
    function updateElements() {
        var disableIt = !$(this).is(':checked');

        $(this).closest('li').find('select').prop('disabled', disableIt);
    }

    function updateElements2() {
        var disableIt = !$(this).val();

        $(this).closest('li').find('select').prop('disabled', disableIt);
        $(this).closest('li').find('.zone-on-off').prop('checked', !disableIt);
    }   

    // Setting up initial state
    $(".zone-on-off").each(updateElements);

    // check and enable / disable selects
    $(".zone-on-off").on('click', updateElements);

    // enable selects when name is inputted
    $(".zone-name").on('input', updateElements2);    
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/555f2yan/2/)

Or, you can go this way:

```
$(function () {
    function updateElements() {
        var parentEl = $(this).closest('li');
        var checkboxEl = parentEl.find('.zone-on-off');
        var inputEl = parentEl.find('.zone-name');
        var selectEl = parentEl.find('select');

        var disableIt = true;

        if ($(this).is('[type=checkbox]')) {
            disableIt = !checkboxEl.is(':checked');
        }
        else {
            disableIt = !inputEl.val();
        }

        selectEl.prop('disabled', disableIt);
        checkboxEl.prop('checked', !disableIt);
    }

    // Setting up initial state
    $(".zone-on-off").each(updateElements);

    // check and enable / disable selects
    $(".zone-on-off").on('click', updateElements);

    // enable selects when name is inputted
    $(".zone-name").on('input', updateElements);    
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/555f2yan/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt, not sure it's better by much, but it works:

```
function enable(el){ 
   $(el).parents('li').find('select').prop("disabled", false);
}
function disable(el){
   $(el).parents('li').find('select').prop("disabled", "disabled");
}
function check(){
    var el = typeof arguments[0] == "object" ? arguments[0] : this;
    el.checked ? enable(el) : disable(el);
}
function update(e){
    e.type=="change" && this.value ? enable(this) : disable(this);
    e.type=="click" && check(this);
    e.type=="keypress" && e.which == 13 && $(this).blur() && enable(this);
}
$(".zone-on-off").each(check);
$(".zone-on-off").click(update);
$(".zone-name").change(update);
$('.zone-name').keypress(update);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a better UI, use `<label>`

```
<label>On / Off: <input type="checkbox" id="zone_1" class="zone-on-off" /></label>
```

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/555f2yan/5/)***

```
$(".zone-on-off").change(function() {           // IO selects
    $(this).closest("li").find("select").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
}).change();                                    // Trigger to perform the initial check

$(".zone-name").on("input keyup", function(e) { // IO if value inputted
    if(e.which === 13) this.blur();
    $(this).closest("li").find(".zone-on-off").prop("checked", this.value).change();
});
```

The above does even a bit more than your initial code (toggles checkboxes *live* as you type etc...) See the demo.

Answer (score 0):

For something simple like this you can easily use find to drill down in short lines of code to the node you want to reach. You can also instead of creating multiple events to do the same thing, create one event and make sure it gets triggered. In the following code I did that with 'change', checkbox click is change, using spacebar to check is change, typing enter in the input is change.

```
$('.zone-on-off').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parents('li')
           .find('select')
           .prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked') ? false : 'disabled')
}).trigger('change');
$('.zone-name').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).parents("li")
               .find('.zone-on-off')
               .prop("checked", $(this).val().length == 0 ? false : 'checked')
               .trigger('change');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k76Lk614/1/